# how to return an array value to dynamically created elements with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of values and when I click on a dynamically created div, one of the values is randomly assigned to it. I'd like to display the value of the array item on the page when I click on the dynamically created div, but I can't figure out how to do it. I get the values returned when I use console.log or alert, but for the life of me can't figure out how to get the values to display on the actual page. I am pretty new to javascript and would appreciate any help on this - here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="gameboard"></div>
```

the 16 dynamically created divs are created under the #gameboard div and have the class .cards, I've styled them with css.

```
#gameboard {
display: flex;
width: 800px;
height: 575px;
min-height: 575px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 1rem;
padding-bottom: 1rem;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: #dadfe8;
}
.cards {
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
padding-top: 2rem;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #3065ba;
font-size: 4rem;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

here is the javascript:

```
var tileImages = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'];
var gameboard = document.getElementById('gameboard');
var solutionArray = tileImages.concat(tileImages); 

shuffleArray(solutionArray);
console.log(solutionArray);  to
function shuffleArray(d) {
 for (var c = d.length - 1; c > 0; c--) {
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (c + 1));
  var a = d[c];
  d[c] = d[b];
  d[b] = a;
 }
return d
};

startGame();

function startGame() {
 var clearedBoard = gameboard.innerHTML = "";
 for (var i=0; i<= ((solutionArray.length)-1); i++) {
  var cards = gameboard.innerHTML += '<div class="cards"></div>';
 }
};
var randomValue = gameboard.onclick = function() {
console.log(tileImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * tileImages.length)]);
};
```

Comment: That `to` shouldn't be there I assume? With that typo fixed just add the value in your `div` that you append: `gameboard.innerHTML += '<div class="cards"> ' + solutionArray[i] + '</div>';`. Also the double assignments on a single line isn't necessary.

Comment: hmm, this adds all the values of the array to the dynamiclaly created elements. I'm trying to just have each one show individually only when I click on the respective div. (not sure where that rogue "to" came from)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track!

Just move the display logic from the gameboard to the cards themselves.

To do that, use the [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) api to create the cards instead of defining them as strings. Then it is easy to attach an onclick callback that handles it's display logic.

```
function startGame() {
for (var i = 0; i <= ((solutionArray.length) - 1); i++) {
    var card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add('cards');
    card.onclick = function() {
        this.innerHTML = tileImages[Math.floor(Math.random() * tileImages.length)];
    }
    gameboard.appendChild(card);
}
```

}

It's also probably a good idea to remove the rogue 'to' in line 6.

**EDIT:** Removed the arguments from startGame function

Comment: Thanks for responding. Not sure where that wayward 'to' came from. I tried your solution but just got a blank page. No divs were created and the array values weren't returned.

Comment: My bad, remove the arguments from the function as per my edit and it should be good.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now.